# When does the Psion Power Point recency limit count?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

I'm a bit confused by the below and just want to gain clarification. In the book it says,

> Recent Manifesting Limit/Rest Interruptions
>   If a psionic character has manifested powers recently, the drain on his resources reduces his capacity to regain power points. When he regains power points for the coming day, all power points he has used within the last 8 hours count against his daily limit.

Does this only count if you are interrupted during your rest or is this anytime you use Power Points within 8hrs before resting?

Comment: I'm not super proficient in 3.5 so please double check the title I gave it to make sure it represent your question well. It will help others with the same query find this one (and the answers provided).

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent power point spending limitation, just like spells, counts for any use of your power points (even depositing them in cognizance crystals) from the 8 hours leading up to the moment you take a full-round action to recover your power points. Usually this only matters for interruptions late at night or when making camp, but elans, elves, and other people with short rest cycles (such as those wearing a *ring of sustenance*) feel the loss when they rest for less than 8 hours after using power points.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for taking the time to clarify. Much appreciated :)